# Error Message in regards to Python code in databricks

Tags: python, pyspark

Trying to analyze tables in databricks for work, and I keep getting the same error message.

```
quality_records = (spark.read
                .table('edl_ops_esda.quality_records_all_sites')
                .select('*')
               )

lot_tying = (spark.read
                .table('edf_prd_cdl_ops_edl_publish.src_tw_ncms_lot_tying_view')
                .select('*')
               )

TableA = quality_records.join(lot_tying, quality_records.TR_ID == lot_tying.tr_id, how = 'right')

TableA.filter((TableA['material_group'] == 'GM0200' | TableA['material_group'] == 'GM0700'))
```

As soon as I add the filters for my tableA, I keep getting this error message
py4j.Py4JException: Method or([class java.lang.String]) does not exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you print TableA schema?

Comment: Yes I can, display works as well.

Comment: try lit('GM0200') wherever you wanna compare string equals.. for example `(TableA['material_group'] == lit('GM0200') | TableA['material_group'] == lit('GM0700'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use isin, since you are filtering on the same column

```py
TableA.filter(TableA.material_group.isin('GM0200', 'GM0700'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incorrect. You need to wrap each comparison statement in each own group

```py
((TableA['material_group'] == 'GM0200') | (TableA['material_group'] == 'GM0700'))
```